# Reputation change from unrelated post

Tags: support, reputation

I just noticed a weird thing in my reputation tab on StackOverflow.

[image: my reputation tab on SO]

That last question mentioned (but not linked, had to find it via search): [In xampp 1.7.4 pdftk doesnt work it gives UNLINK error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6595959/877465)

I must have amnesia as I have no memory of ever interacting with this post. I don't even know what xampp and pdftk are so I don't know why I would even be interested in such a question. 2 reputation points more or less is not a big deal, but the fact I got rep change from question I've never seen before is odd and I'm wondering what happened.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you [edited the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/316759) and got reputation from it.  Since the answer has been removed, you lose the reputation.

Your edit was approved on Aug 9, 2011:

> [image]

The answer that you edited was deleted and converted to a comment:

> [image]

You received 2 reputation points for the approved suggested edit. Since the answer has now been deleted so as a result you lose those points.

Comment: I can't see this link and there seem to be no revisions of the question.

Comment: @fichek changed the link

Comment: Yeah, that's the same link @MartijnPieters posted, but I don't see why I would lose rep there as the edit is still in place.

Comment: No, he didn't edit the question. He edited the *answer*.

Comment: @fichek: No, the answer has been deleted. You never touched the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters correct, fixed. I incorrectly said question and meant they edited the answer.

Comment: The screenshot you just added is a comment, not an answer, just like your link. The comment is also still there along with my suggested edit, so I don't see how I could lose points from it.

Comment: Ah, so the answer was converted to a comment? That does make sense, thank you.

Comment: @fichek yes the answer was converted to a comment and then deleted.  Once you get 10k+ rep you will be able to see deleted answers.

Answer (score 3):

You once [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/316759) to the answer and it was accepted, giving you a +2 point reputation increase.

When the answer was deleted you lost those points again.

Comment: You linked a comment, not an answer. And that comment is still there. I'm now even more confused than I was :)

Comment: @fichek: I did not link a comment, I linked to your suggested edit, which was approved. The *answer* the edit was made to is now gone. Click on the header of that suggested edit to be led back to the question; if you have 10k+ on SO you can see the deleted answer as well.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused because there is a comment on the question identical to the answer which I made suggested edit for, and which you linked. Now I think I get it. Answer was converted to a comment somehow and in that process I lost rep from my suggested edit since answer is marked as removed. I guess this would be easier to figure out if I had over 10k rep on SO and was able to see removed answer.

Comment: @fichek: Right, I had not seen the comment at all; indeed, the moderator converted the answer to a comment, as it should have been all along.